# How to drain sump pump discharge line?

Tags: plumbing

My house has a sump pump, with a PVC discharge pipe shallow-buried for a long distance outside. Inside the basement near the sump pump, there is a 1-way valve, which keeps the discharge pipe full of water.

Several times over the years, I've found that the discharge pipe joints have split outside. It finally dawned on me that the cause is the water in the pipe freezing during the winter. After examining different solutions, the best one looks like draining the water from the pipe before winter (the sump pump only runs during the rainy period in the spring and fall, so it should stay drained over the winter, or I could drain it again if necessary).

My idea is to manually force the sump pump to discharge virtually all the water in the sump bucket. Then drain the water in the discharge pipe back into the sump bucket. My calculations are that the resulting water level in the bucket will still be low enough to not trigger the pump. Alternatively, I could collect it in buckets and dump it outside.

So my question is how to add the drain capability in a simple way. I could cut the pipe above the 1-way valve, insert a tee with a ball valve and some plumbing to direct the water. I don't have experience with this kind of plumbing job, so it would be a lot of work, with a bunch of components, adapters, and glue joints, and many potential failure points. A simpler approach would be to use something like a self-tapping saddle valve, like what is used to add a water line for a refrigerator. So far, though, I haven't found one designed for use on pipe the size of the discharge line (1-1/2" schedule 40, with an OD of 1.9").

Is there a simple solution for a DIYer with limited plumbing experience?

Comment: Remove the one way valve.  Water runs down hill most times, so if the outside has a proper slope it should drain.

Comment: The only reason I can envision for the sump to need a 1-way valve (commonly referred to as a "check valve"), is that the drain pipe is sloped incorrectly. That means that the drain end is _higher_ than the pump end, so water will run back into the house. Maybe look into fixing the slope of the drain pipe and eliminate the check valve...

Comment: The property doesn't have the right slope. There isn't a low area for the discharge. There is also a very high water table, so a dry well wouldn't be a good solution (and expensive). Without the 1-way valve, the water in the discharge pipe would normally cause the sump pump to run continuously. Draining the water from the pipe seems like a simple and cheap solution.

Comment: In that case, add a tee after check valve with an air pig  and blow the water out.  Will probably need a decent size air compressor, not those dinky emergency tire inflators.

Comment: @crip659, That occurred to me, but wouldn't the air just bubble through the water? I envisioned that it would blow out some water just through the turbulence, but that most of the water would remain. Is my assumption bad?

Comment: The air should act like a plug to push water out.  Complete drainage might not happen, but a half full pipe should not break due to freezing, it usually takes a full pipe to burst.  The water will need to go somewhere, either out the end or back into the pump.

Comment: install the sump pump as suction, on the end of the drain pipe

Comment: Re-bury the pipe below the frost line? Use a surface pipe which will drain, or which is easy to replace if it doesn't?

Comment: Where does your drain pipe discharge?  Does it have a belly in it or something?

Comment: @Huesmann, the pipe exits the basement about 6" underground, runs roughly level for about 45' and exits the ground. Then undulates mostly above ground for 25' in a wooded area with dense tree roots. The discharge is higher, and into an area that becomes swampy. Trying to alter the pipe would be a big, expensive job. Simply draining the water seems like a simple, cheap solution.

Comment: @Dolly then your issue is where to drain it.  Many municipalities don't allow storm drainage (which this is) to be drained into municipal sanitary lines.

Comment: @Huesmann, as mentioned in the question, the water would either go back into the almost empty sump bucket or into buckets that are emptied outside. The issue is a simple way to drain the pipe. An ideal solution would be something like a self-tapping saddle valve, but these don't appear to be available for a pipe this size. I was hoping that someone with plumbing familiarity knew a simple, available solution.

Comment: The easiest way to drain the pipe is not to put any water into it...